# Can hive create an temorary table so I can get a small table for further queries?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table, the schema is as below:

```
 struct TBL{
   1:optional string category;
   2:optional string endpoint; 
   3:optional string priority; 
   4:optional i64 timestap;
   5:optional string traceId;   
   6:optional string rpcId;     
   7:optional string businessId;
   8:optional string message;   
   9:optional int date;    
}
```

I only care about `8:optional string message;` 
`message` field is `log`.

I have a list of urls some of which can be found in the `message` filed. I need find which urls can be found in the table. In the `message` filed, the url always comes with `"getRequestURL"` such as

```
10.128.226.31,[INFO  2019-03-13 10:00:18.770] [resin-port-9300-44] [aaaLiMKyYK9bNbetoyhLw_-301570423] com.example.cashpay.filter.StaticFilter.doFilter(StaticFilter.java:99) [getRequestURL=http://www.example.com/merchant/deduct/query/v3]
```

The table is very large. 
I want to filter the table first, say:

```
select message from TBL where message like '%getRequestURL%' and date ='20190319'
```

and then I can use union query to found which urls are in the filtered table above.
say:

```
    select 'com/res/doc/eula/help.html', count(1) from filtered_tbl where message like 'com/res/doc/eula/help.html'
    union
    select 'com/charge/bank/alipay_wap/', count(1) from filtered_tbl where message like 'com/charge/bank/'
    union
    select 'com/reductionActivity/queryRegisterStatus', count(1) from filtered_tbl where message like 'com/reductionActivity/queryRegisterStatus'
    union
    select 'com/charge/pushcmd', count(1) from filtered_tbl where message like 'com/charge/pushcmd'
union......
```

Does hive support filter first? If it support, then what can I do?

Comment: you are on the right track. you might want to use regex too.

Comment: Positive. Hive does support filter. And better use OR in the where in single query instead of multiple queries w union all

Comment: @leftjoin Then, what can I do to filter first?

Comment: The use-case is not clear. Are you going to use filtered table many times in queries in the same Hive session? And the question is how to create filtered TEMPORARY table? Or how to filter the table once and use it many times in single query